# How to avoid circular references with member callbacks & shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, callback, shared-ptr

In our codebase, we have a plethora of cases like the following:

```
auto f = std::make_shared<Foo>();
auto b = std::make_shared<Bar>();
//void Foo::DoStuff( std::shared_ptr<Foo>, int ) 
auto func = std::bind( &Foo::DoStuff, f, std::_1 );
b->RegisterFunc( func );
```

Obviously, pocketing the `shared_ptr` in a stored callback is generally a bad idea, as it oft causes `f` to never be destructed. Normally, you can just pass in a `weak_ptr` and check whether it is still valid on execution.

Unfortunately, `DoStuff()` modifies internal state of the `Foo` object, and is a member function, so it **requires** the pointer to be valid to avoid crashes. Which causes circular references, and requires manual intervention like calling `Foo::Shutdown()` or something to remove them.

Is there a way to work around the circular references storing callbacks of member functions?

Note: For the purposes of the question, I am **requiring** the bound function to be a non-static member function. It is too ubiquitous in our code to justify completely reworking every example, even if it is clearly a design oversight.

Comment: For context, the code runs on a system we own end to end. Most processes actually just allocate/destruct on power on/off; this hides the problem (mostly). Where it doesn't, we take the explicit call Foo::Shutdown approach.

Comment: If you define func via a lambda that captures a shared_ptr<Foo> by value, it will be destroyed when you destroy func and not before.

Comment: Where is the circular reference? `func` refers to `f`, `b` refers to `func` .. there's no circle.

Comment: In this example I'm guessing you meant to include a reference in a callback from `a` to `b` as well, which would create a circular reference. If that's the case, you might want to edit your question to reflect that

Answer (score 1):

As you say, you have to use `weak_ptr` and check that it's valid. `weak_ptr` can be used to create valid pointers to the object, so you can still call `DoStuff()` on pointers obtained from a `weak_ptr`. It's not clear to me why you think `weak_ptr` will not work.

Here's your example, but now it's showing a potential circular reference that's avoided with use of `weak_ptr`

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

struct Foo {
    int x = 0;
    using callback_t = std::function<void()>;
    std::vector<callback_t> callbacks;

    void DoStuff() { x = 1; } //mutate some state
    void RegisterFunc(callback_t callback) { callbacks.push_back(std::move(callback)); }
};

using Bar = Foo;

template <class T>
auto wrap_shared_ptr_callback(const std::shared_ptr<T>& p, void(T::*f)()) {
    return [p = std::weak_ptr{ p }, f]() {
        auto ptr = p.lock();
        if (ptr) (*ptr.*f)();
    };
}

void create_circular_reference(std::shared_ptr<Foo> f, std::shared_ptr<Bar> b) {
    auto f_callback = wrap_shared_ptr_callback(f, &Foo::DoStuff);
    b->RegisterFunc( f_callback );
    auto b_callback = wrap_shared_ptr_callback(b, &Bar::DoStuff);
    f->RegisterFunc( b_callback );

    // test callbacks
    b->callbacks.front()();
    f->callbacks.front()();
}

int main() {
    auto f = std::make_shared<Foo>();
    auto b = std::make_shared<Bar>();

    // keep weak ptrs so we can check they've been destroyed correctly
    auto f_w = std::weak_ptr{ f };
    auto b_w = std::weak_ptr{ b };

    create_circular_reference(std::move(f), std::move(b));

    assert(f_w.expired());
    assert(b_w.expired());
}
```